# Angular 1/Javascript - alternative to lodash omit and delete operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have a child component where I have to delete properties from an object.

Normally using Lodash it should work with this code :

```
this.current.obj = omit(this.current.obj, ['sellerSupportWeb', 'sellerSupportAgency', 'sellerSupportAgent'])
```

Just that the current.obj model does not mount up to the parent component

But if I delete the properties from the object with just the operator `delete` it works

```
   delete this.current.obj.sellerSupportAgency
   delete this.current.obj.sellerSupportWeb
   delete this.current.obj.sellerSupportAgent
```

Is there not another alternative that does the same job as delete and omit ?

I do not know if it can help, but for it to work with omit I'm calling the parent object (parent component) on the child component so that I get on it, but I'm looking for another solution since the `current.obj`

```
for (const [index] of this.current.parent.items.entries()) {
  this.current.parent.items[index] = omit(this.current.parent.items[index], ['sellerSupportWeb', 'sellerSupportAgency', 'sellerSupportAgent'])
}
```

Comment: why the question becomes French?

Comment: it is modified.

Comment: Is it? `Je ne sais pas si ça peut aider, mais pour que ça fonctionne with omit je fais appel à l'objet parent (du composant parent) sur le composant fils pour que j'itère sur lui, mais je cherche une autre solution depuis le current.obj`

Comment: It is also modified

Comment: Yes now it is. But also using English it's not clear what you are asking. So `delete` works but you want another method?

Comment: Exactly, I'm looking for another solution / alternative to delete

Comment: There is the `delete` which is more than enough. You can loop over the properties of your object and specify which ones to delete if you want to group the code. But for deleting just three properties, I think that three lines of code are fair enough

Comment: I see, but I'm looking for another solution than the `delete` operator

Comment: You need to tell us `why` you want an alternative, else it sounds like you are looking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to modify the object that is shared between the component and its parent. The object is in an array in the parent component, so I assume that you are using an `ng-repeat` statement. I'm not sure, because you didn't share your component definition nor the instantiation in the parent component template.

When you change the local object reference (with `omit`), the array in the parent component will not be modified. When you change the local object in place (with delete), the local variable will still reference the object in the parent array, and it will be modified in both places (since it is the same object).

Long story short, you have to choose between modifying the array (in the parent), or removing the fields from the local object (and `delete` is the only way to do that). The former would be more angular-like, especially if you use '&'-type event handlers to tell the parent component that you want certain fields to be removed from the object. You could then do something like this:

```
angular.component(...
    bindings: {
        filterObjectHandler: '&onFilterObject'
(...)

this.filterObjectHandler(['sellerSupportWeb', 'sellerSupportAgency', 'sellerSupportAgent']);
```

Or something like that. There is an interesting set of articles [here](https://velesin.io/2016/04/26/angular-1-5-app-as-a-tree-of-components/) about component structure in AngularJS 1.5+.

However, if you just want a way to delete the fields in a way involving a one-liner with an array of fields, you could use this:

```
var obj = this.current.obj;

['sellerSupportWeb', 'sellerSupportAgency', 'sellerSupportAgent'].forEach(function(field) {
    delete obj[field];
});
```

or even:

```
['sellerSupportWeb', 'sellerSupportAgency', 'sellerSupportAgent'].reduce(function(obj, field) {
    delete obj[field];
    return obj;
}, this.current.obj);
```